# CSS Animated Timer displaying strangely on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, css-animations, mobile-safari

We've created an animated timer like so:

[image]

Unfortunately it's looking like this currently on iPad:

[image]

The iPad is on 10.3.3 which is a couple version old but we cant see any CSS/HTML features that are not supported.

Here's the jsfiddle with all the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/liammkenny/58rezv3c/192/

The html structure is fairly simple:

```
<body>
  <div class='timer'>
    <div class="cover wedge"></div>
    <div class="left wedge"></div>
    <div class="right wedge">
    </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <div class="stop"></div>
        <span class="units">123
        </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What's making it display so badly?

Comment: i actually experienced a issue with animations with safari. I suggest you to update it once. Also does it work well with android phones?

Comment: .stop{  heigth: 20px;}  Please correct the spelling 'height'